# HubSpot SSO setup with WSO2 Identity Server - encountering '405 - Method Not Allowed' error

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server, hubspot

I am attempting to set up Single Sign-On (SSO) for HubSpot using WSO2 Identity Server. I have followed the documentation provided at https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/provisioning-users-to-hubspot/ and successfully completed all the steps. However, when I try to access the user portal at https://localhost:9443/user-portal/, I am facing a '405 - Method Not Allowed' error. It seems that the requested HTTP method is not allowed for the endpoint.

I would like to inquire if there is an alternative method available to integrate SSO with HubSpot, or if there is a known fix for this '405' error when accessing the user portal in WSO2 Identity Server.

Furthermore, during the SSO setup in HubSpot, it requires specific details such as the Identity Provider Identifier or Issuer URL, Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL, and X.509 Certificate. I am unsure of where to find these details within WSO2 Identity Server after following the provided documentation and completing the setup.

Any assistance, suggestions, or insights would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you have used IS-5.10.0 for Provisioning users to Hubspot? Or else did you use the latest product?

Comment: I used the latest 6.1.0

Comment: This is the latest documentation for Provisioning users to Hubspot.
Can you try this out and see?

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/hubspot-provisioning/#configuring-hubspot

Comment: Yes, i have followed the documentation and configured accordinglly using admin cedentials on https://localhost:9443/carbon/ but a the end when trying to access https://localhost:9443/myaccount it returns 405-Method Not Allowed

Comment: Hi @Beth.A, There is confusion about what you are trying to achieve. Your objective is to  `set up Single Sign-On (SSO) for HubSpot using WSO2 Identity Server.` It means users in WSO2 would be able to login to hubspot application via wso2 and single signon to other applications registered with WSO2 IS. but the following guide is about provisioning users in WSO2 IS to hubspot. So could you please mention your objective and actions?

Comment: Regarding the 405 error on accessing user-portal, `https://localhost:9443/user-portal` is not a supported URL in IS-6.1.0. That particular user profile management application should be accessed via `https://localhost:9443/myaccount` in IS-6.1.0. As per the above comments it seems you are getting 405 error for myaccount access as well. Did you try to access myaccount in a fresh IS setup without any of your configuration?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna yes my objective is to set up Single Sign-On (SSO) for HubSpot using WSO2 Identity Server meaning I want users in Wso2 to be able to login in to a Hubspot Portal.